# Are XML Schema regular expressions compatible to JavaScript/ECMAScript regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, xsd, ecmascript-5, jsonschema

I'm an author of a XML-Schema-to-JSON-Schema compiler/transformer. A user recently asked if it would be possible to also support `xs:pattern` in JSON Schema.

JSON Schema does support [regular expressions](http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#regular-expressions) so theoretically this should be possible.

However, this assumes that regular expression syntax and semantic of XML Schema are compatible to those of the JavaScript/ECMAScript. Because if they're not I'll probably won't be able to parse and translate one regular expression dialect into another one without much effort.

I can't answer this question without thorough analysis of both specifications:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10

So I'd like to ask:

**Are XML Schema regular expressions compatible to JavaScript/ECMAScript  regular expressions?**

Specifically, can I use a valid regular expression from the XML Schema in JavaScript (via `RegExp` or similar)?

I've read that XML Schema regular expressions are rather limited so hopefully they'll work in more powerful environment, but it's hard for me to say if this is a case here.

I'll assume XML Schema 1.0 and ECMAScript 5.1 here.

Comment: They are not compatible. In XML Shema you can use Unicode category classes and you can't use them in JS (ES5, current implementation). Also, character class subtraction is not supported in JS regex. Also, `\w`, `\d` and `\s` shorthand classes can match Unicode symbols, and in ES5 they do not. `\i`, `\l`, `\c`, `\C` "multi-character escapes" are not supported in ES5 either.

Comment: @stribizhev Would you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ES5 and XML Schema regex syntaxes are not compatible.

In XML Shema, you can use Unicode category classes (referred to as [*category escapes*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#charprop)) and you can't use them in JavaScript ES5.

Besides, [character class subtraction](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-charexpr) is not supported in JavaScript regex.

Also, `\w`, `\d` and `\s` shorthand classes can match Unicode symbols, and in ES5 they do not. `\i`, `\l`, `\c`, `\C` ["multi-character escapes"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-ccesN) are not supported in ES5 either.

Comment: Furthermore, "." in XML Schema matches any Unicode character (including astral characters) whereas in ES5 it matches one half of a surrogate pair. That changes with Unicode regular expressions in ES6. There are other minor differences such as the meaning of \d.